# How can Kirchhoff's law of radiation be proven more rigorously and what does it really mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, thermal-radiation

Kirchhoff's law of radiation states that emission factor equals absorbtion factor for any material body: $\epsilon = a$

I never understood this really: Lets say there a body which reflects totally any radiation from its surface is put into a black-radiation cavity. That would mean that thermal equilibrium can never be reached by radiation because no energy is ever received by the body.

Q1: On the other hand, when I heat such body internally, will it really not radiate? For the moment see no reason why I should not feel warming in front of a heated mirror. Is this really what the law says?

Q2: All the proofs of above statement I have ever seen assume thermal equilibrium as a premise. But for instance our sun is (in my opinion, maybe I'm wrong) not in thermal equilibrium with any other system; nevertheless its radiation is according to a black-body. So why?

Q3: How can Kirchhoff's law be profen more rigorously as in https://www.vedantu.com/question-answer/state-kirchhoffs-law-of-radiation-and-prove-it-class-11-physics-cbse-5f3f9f2a7367fe538f457be6

In fact all "academic" prooves I have seen use this extremely simple chain of argumentation which appears for me to include a circular conclusion. Is this really the whole story? It looks a bit strange for me that a very general statement can be established just by second law of thermodynamics without using the "microphysics" of the body under consideration.
I would appreciate if somebody could give a link where the statement is derived on a more advanced advanced level.

Comment: The law does, for instance, not apply to your smart phone or the sun or your own body, so it is not a general statement, at all. Thermal equilibrium is a very special case.

Comment: The radiation from the Sun isn't a blackbody because it isn't in thermal equilibrium with its surroundings.

Comment: A mirror may be optically very reflective but may not be at other wavelengths.

Comment: as commented above by Flattermann and @ProfRob the sun's emission is not that of the black-body see the yellow background in https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Solar_spectrum_en.svg. Maybe you should rephrase why is it that while it is not a BB emission, at a first glance, the shape seems to be quite close to be so? For that question read the rest of the WP article in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunlight.

Comment: @hypnortex the reason being that it achieves an optical depth of 1 at a similar temperature for most wavelengths in the optical, thanks to opacity due to H$^{-}$ ions.

Comment: Radiation from the Sun is NOT blackbody; only an upper luminosity limit corresponds to the black body curve, detailed analysis shows spectrum of, for instance, helium (discovered in sunlight before the element was detected on Earth).